# photo sharing from android mobile to DLNA enabled devices

Tags: android

i have a task to do that is i take a photo from my andriod mobile and suddenly i want display that image into Dlna enbled device.

how i start my project give me some idea to do ..

Answer (score 0):

"Dlna enabled device" you are talking about should a be a Digital Media Render(DMR), and you need to implement a Digital Media Server (DMS) and Digital Media Controller (DMC) on your android phone.
You will use DMC to push a photo from DMS to the DMR.